# Merge two tables in Postgresql giving preference to one particular table

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables, Users and Masters. Users are having User specific settingkey-value. Masters is having master settingkey-value. I want to display key-value from the two tables, where

1. if users do not have that particular key, need to take it from masters
   2  if the users do not exists in the table, need to display all from masters key-value
2. if users having key-value, have to display users key-value

Example:

[image: UsersTable]

[image: MasterTable]

[image: DesiredResult]

Inputs being -  UserID and appID = 1.

I tried with left join combination, but not getting desired result if Users do not exists at all in the Users table.

Could you please give me some advise.

Comment: You need a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` if you want to include records from the first table that don't have a match in the second.

Comment: Left join + coalesce

Comment: No, you need a full outer join because only Master contains 'ddd' and only User contains 'ccc'. Both are expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=80dd2387de94345788bf27470313cb97)

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(m.app_id, u.app_id) as app_id,
    COALESCE(m.setting_key, u.setting_key) as setting_key,
    COALESCE(u.setting_value, m.setting_value) as setting_value   -- 2
FROM 
    master_table m
FULL OUTER JOIN                                                   -- 1
    user_table u
ON m.app_id = u.app_id AND m.setting_key = u.setting_key
WHERE COALESCE(m.app_id, u.app_id) = 1                            -- 3
   AND (u.user_id = 1 OR u.user_id IS NULL)
```

1. You need a `FULL OUTER JOIN` to join also data set that the other table does not contain
2. `COALESCE(a, b)` gives you the first non-null value. So, if a (here the `user` value) is available, it will be returned. Otherwise b (here the `master` value)
3. Filter by `app_id` and `user_id`; second needs to be filtered by `user_id == NULL` too, to get all `setting_key`s. Of course, you could use here `COALESCE` as well: `COALESCE(u.user_id, 1)` whereas the last 1 is the specific user_id you're asking

---

**Edit**: If User does not exist, give out the Masters values for `app_id`:

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=26f73c59edc716059f180dde650b33f5)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (app_id, setting_key)                      -- 3
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        COALESCE(user_app_id, master_app_id) AS app_id,       -- 2
        COALESCE(user_setting_key, master_setting_key) AS setting_key,
        COALESCE(user_setting_value, master_setting_value) AS setting_value,
        user_id
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            app_id as master_app_id,
            setting_key as master_setting_key,
            setting_value as master_setting_value,
            null as user_id,
            null as user_app_id,
            null as user_setting_key,
            null as user_setting_value
        FROM
            master_table m
        
        UNION                                                 -- 1

        SELECT
            *
        FROM 
            master_table m
        FULL OUTER JOIN
            user_table u
        ON m.app_id = u.app_id AND m.setting_key = u.setting_key
    ) s
) s
WHERE app_id = 1
    AND (user_id = 2 OR user_id IS NULL)
ORDER BY app_id, setting_key, user_id NULLS LAST              -- 3
```

This is a little more complicated. You need a separate data set for `user_id == NULL` which could be fetched. So, the `NULL` user represents the unknown user.

1. You can achieve this by adding the Master table with `NULL` values using an `UNION`.
2. Now you can create the expected columns with the `COALESCE()` functions as described above.
3. The third trick is using the `DISTINCT ON` clause on the app_id and the setting_key columns. When you ordered the `NULL` columns from the default `UNION` part in (1) last, then the `DISTINCT ON` will fetch the user record. However, when the user didn't exist, then the `DISTINCT` ON will fetch the default Master record.

Comment: Let me try this. I saw the last comment, only.

Comment: If the UserID = 1 do not exists, this will not return anything. I need to populate virtually, all settings for userID = 1, even if UserID = 1 do not exists in Users table. Thats where I am stuck.

Comment: @SayanB Ok, that was a requirement you should have mentioned in the question because it makes the query a little more complicated. However, I added a solution for that.

Comment: yes thats one of the requirement, I had mentioned in the beginning , may be you have overlooked. Thanks again, for helping me out. Let me check this.

Comment: Yes, this concept worked, I had to modify a little bit for my purpose, but the concept works, thanks a lot.